# ¿Cómo puedo enviar un valor a un input mediante un botón?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html5

Bueno estoy programando una calculadora y quisiera saber cómo hacer que al presionar un botón de determinado número me salga en el input tipo texto ¿alguien me podría ayudar? por favor.

Comment: Por favor comparte el código de lo que ya llevas intentado

Answer (score 3):

te mando como se haría!! Le he asignado un valor al botón para poder recogerlo después de pulsarlo y ponerlo en el input

```js
function sendData() {
      document.getElementById('reciver').value += document.getElementById('five').innerHTML;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" name="" value="" id="reciver">
    <button type="button" name="button" value="5" id="five" onclick="sendData()">5</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <body>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="reciver">
        <button id="five">5</button>
        <p ></p>
    </div>
    <script>

        function sendData(){
            /*el valor del 'five' es igual a la suma interactiva de 'reciver'*/
        var x=document.getElementById('reciver').value += document.getElementById('five').innerHTML;
        }
        /*creamos el evento desde javascript*/
        var btn=document.getElementById("five");
        btn.addEventListener("mousedown",sendData);


    </script>
</body>
```